# How to transfer data between Parent and Child View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I have tried looking at answers on similar questions to this, but I am not particularly experienced and have had trouble following them, so any help would be much appreciated!  My situation is as follows: when I press a button in my Parent ViewController, the following code is used to call a Child ViewController (by the way, the Child is actually a TableViewController, but it seems to work fine "thinking" it's a normal ViewController?):

```
controller = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "People"))
addChildViewController(controller!)
controller?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 394, height: 300)
self.view.addSubview((controller?.view)!)
controller?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

What I would then like is to transfer an array from the Parent to the Child, where it will be used as the TableView's data?

Secondly, when I select a cell from the Child's TableView, I would like the relevant information to be sent to the Parent, and for the Child to disappear.
In case it is of interest, I have managed to close the Child under different circumstances (when a click occurs in the Parent while the Child is displayed) using the following:

```
controller?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
controller?.view.removeFromSuperview()
controller?.removeFromParentViewController()
```

I would really appreciate any advice, even if it's a link to something which would help!

Comment: you can pass the array just like the way you pass data between any two view controllers. after `addChildViewController(controller!)` line, you can just add `controller.array = self.array`. and to return, you can use a delegate method.

Comment: You can make property in `parentsViewVontroller` and `parentsViewVontroller's` instance to `childViewController` and pass value to this variable OR you can make a delegate of `childViewController` and can receive the events back OR you can use the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass value from Parent to Child Controller like this

```
controller = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "People"))
    addChildViewController(controller!)
    controller?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 394, height: 300)
    controller.tableDataSource = // Pass your required value to child controller
    self.view.addSubview((controller?.view)!)
    controller?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Now you want to transfer back your select value to Parent view controller. For this purpose your have a create a Delegate in ChildController like

```
@protocol ChildControllerDelegate : class {
    func selectedValue(Value : String)
}
```

After that make a variable of that delegate in ChildController like this

```
weak var delegate : ChildControllerDelegate?
```

and when in rowDidSelect method add following code

```
if(delegate != nil) {
   delegate.selectedValue(Value :"Your selected value")
}
```

Now step when you are going to show ChildController from ParentController at that time you have to set that `delegate` object to ParentController like this

```
controller = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "People"))
    addChildViewController(controller!)
    controller?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 394, height: 300)
    controller.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview((controller?.view)!)
    controller?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

and after that just implement the delegate method in ParentController like that

```
func selectedValue(Value : String) {
   // you select val 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This.**

First Create Public Method For Add And Remove childVC.

**For Add childVC.**

```
public class func openChildViewController(parentVC:UIViewController, with childVC:UIViewController){

        parentVC.addChildViewController(childVC)
        childVC.view.frame = parentVC.view.frame
        parentVC.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
        parentVC.didMove(toParentViewController: childVC)
    }
```

**For Remove childVC.**

```
   public class func removeChildViewController(childVC:UIViewController){

        childVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        childVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        childVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
```

Use Above Method.

**1.ParentVC.swift**

```
class ParentVC: UIViewController , ChildVCDelegate  {

     var arrType = NSMutableArray()

    //add ChildVC
    @IBAction func btnAddChildVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ChildVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildVC") as! ChildVC
        PickerVC.arrPass = arrType //for data passing create any object in ChildVC for ex. arrPass is NSMutableArray
        ChildVC.delegate = self
        openChildViewController(parentVC: self, with: ChildVC)
    }

     // MARK: ChildVC Delegate
   func SetSelectedPickerValue(strSelectOption: String) {
                print(strSelectOption)
        }
    }

}
```

**2.ChildVC.swift**

```
class ChildVC: UIViewController{

    // MARK: Variable for ParentVCData Passing
     var arrPass = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(arrPass)
    }

    //Remove ChildVC
    @IBAction func btnRemoveChildVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.SetSelectedPickerValue!(strSelectOption: “any String you pass ChildVC To ParentVC”)
        removeChildViewController(childVC: self)
    }
}
// MARK: Create Delegate Method
@objc protocol ChildVCDelegate{
     @objc optional func SetSelectedPickerValue(strSelectOption:String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Cast the `controller` to the appropriate class for the child view controller (I'm using `ChildViewController` below, but hopefully you have a more descriptive name); and
- Pass the array (which I guessed you might have called `people`, but use whatever your array names are in these two respective view controllers) from the current view controller (the parent) to this new child view controller.

Thus:

```
let child = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "People") as! ChildViewController
addChildViewController(child)
child.people = people
child.view.frame = ...
view.addSubview(child.view)
child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Personally, I wouldn't hard code the child coordinates like you did in your original question. I'd set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) to `false` and then add the appropriate leading/trailing/top/bottom constraints, but that's up to you. It was just too painful to see hardcoded coordinates in your example.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!  Was going to get things working first then put the autoresizing in afterwards (pretty new to this so I imagine it may well not be the right way to do things!)